# Easiest Ancistrus to breed

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater

To follow up on a previous question of mine and some information provided in an answer there ([Ancistrus breeding in rock pile](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18569/ancistrus-breeding-in-rock-pile))

What Ancistrus is the easiest to breed?

My reasoning around this would be that the cheaper they are, the easier they are to breed (hence the price). So the pet store price should be a pretty good indicator, no?

Comment: Hey, I'm going to comment not answer since I think getting additional opinions may help, but here's a couple sites that may help you, I've used several times. I breed fish :)

Comment: https://www.planetcatfish.com/common/genus.php?genus_id=4

Comment: https://www.planetcatfish.com/shanesworld/shanesworld.php?article_id=328